# Inspect the return value of a function in lldb

Tags: debugging, return-value, lldb

Is it possible to inspect the return value of a function in lldb assuming the return value is not assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step out of the function, and see return value in inspector. Here is my screenshot:

[image]

See article for more details: https://gist.github.com/schwa/7812916

Comment: Note this only works if you exit the function with a "step out".  lldb doesn't yet track all step over's and step-in's to see if one of them exited a function.

Comment: This answers the question only for XCode not for lldb

Answer (score 27):

Answer is wrong so I will post correct one.

To inspect return value you need to `(lldb) finish` (abbr. for `thread step-out`) from function which return value you want to examine and then use:

```
(lldb) thread info
```

This will give you output similar to this:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x28955, (frame variables  and stuff), stop reason = step out
Return value: (NSMenu *) $3 = 0x0000600000065280
```

Having this you can just:

```
(lldb) po $3
```

Note that `gdb` way of inspecting return value by just using `finish` doesn't print anything for lldb.

Additionally as SFeng pointed out if you use Xcode you can just see it in UI inspector after you stepped out from previous function or method.

Comment: Im not seeing any info printed after `finish`.  But `po $x0` seems to have the right value

Comment: @HariKaramSingh That's exactly what I have said, finish for lldb doesn't print anything.

Comment: @tboyce12 This doesn't work for Swift in Xcode 8.3.2. Don't know about other versions.

Comment: @solgar You are second only to clive1.

Comment: Doesn't work on latest clang/lldb lldb-1000.11.38.2

Comment: @TCSGrad It doesn't work for swift up to 4. Haven't checked Swift 5. I'll add this note to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can setting a breakpoint on function's return point(similar to `thread step-out`) and print out the return value. Try this(working on ARM platform):

```
#1 (lldb) br set -n "__FUNCTION_NAME_YOUR_WANT_TO_TRACE" -K false
#2 (lldb) br set -a $lr -o true -G true -C "po $x0"
```

At #1 we create a breakpoint on a __FUNCTION_NAME_YOUR_WANT_TO_TRACE,\ `-K false` make sure we do not skip the prologue in assembly.

Since we do not skip prologue, when the first breakpoint hit, we can retrieve the return address of this function(`bl` and `ble` instruction set the return address to link register, aka `lr`).

At this time we create a breakpoint at return address in #2.

`-o true` means it is a one-shot breakpoint, it would delete itself after hitting;

`-G true` means auto-continue;

`-C "po $x0"` means adding a `po $x0` command to this breakpoint, to print content at x0 register, which stores return value of targeting function.